# how to remove white background during animation?

Tags: kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose, navcontroller

how to remove this background or change it to another?

I tried adding activity.window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.black1) to MainActivity but it didn't help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe7DG.gif)

```
 composable(
            route = OrderDetailsScreens,
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("id") {
                type = NavType.StringType
            }), enterTransition ={
                slideIntoContainer(
                    AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                    animationSpec = tween(700)
                )
            }, exitTransition = {
                 slideOutOfContainer(
                    AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                    animationSpec = tween(700)

                )
            },
            popEnterTransition = {
                slideIntoContainer(
                    AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                    animationSpec = tween(700)
                )
            },
            popExitTransition = {
                slideOutOfContainer(
                    AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                    animationSpec = tween(700)
                )
            }

        ) { backStackEntry ->
            val id = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("id") ?: NO_VALUE
            OrderDetailsScreen(
                id = id,
                navBack = {
                    navController.popBackStack()
                },
                navToCarpets = {
                    navController.navigate(OrderDetailsScreens.Carpets.route + "/$id")
                },
            )
        }
```

and MainActivity

```
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity
            LaunchedEffect(activity) {
                activity.window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.black1)
            }
            MarusTheme(darkColors = darkColors()) {

                this.window.statusBarColor =
                    ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black1)
                navController = rememberNavController()
                RootNavigationGraph(navController = navController)
                AuthState()

            }


        }
    }
```

I tried adding activity.window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.black1) to MainActivity but it didn't help

Comment: you didn't any images

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Modifier.background` in `NavHost`.

```
val color = colorResource(R.color.black1)
NavHost(
    Modifier.background(color)
)
```

Comment: didn't help unfortunately